# Android Annotations Blank Screen

Tags: java, android, annotations

I'm using Android Annotations and I wanted to implement a simple Fragment to test it out, so I'm using it mainly to bind views to their IDs via @ViewById. When I start the fragment, I do the binding via annotation and then use @AfterViews to perform other actions. However, all I see is a blank screen.

**The Flow:** Activity Starts -> Inserts Fragment -> Blank Screen

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_add_buddy)
public class AddBuddyActivityNew extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 * Simply performing frag transaction to place the add from contacts fragment
 * @param savedInstanceState
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.add_buddy_container,     AddFromContactsFragment.newInstance(), ConstantValues.Tag.ADD_FROM_CONTACTS);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

```
@EFragment(R.layout.fragment_add_from_contacts)
public class AddFromContactsFragment extends Fragment implements     LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>,GetUsernamesFromPhoneNumbersListener,AddFrom    ContactsActivityAdapter.AddBuddyInterface, AddBuddyListener,     SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, UsernameExistsListener {
private static final String LOG_TAG =     AddFromContactsFragment.class.getCanonicalName();
private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CONTACTS = 0;
private SessionManager sessionManager;
private LBDatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

HashMap<String,String> numbersAndNames;
AddFromContactsActivityAdapter addFromContactsActivityAdapter;
private ContactsHandler handler;
private Timer timer;

/** UI References */
@ViewById(R.id.add_buddy_button) TextView addBuddyButton;
@ViewById(R.id.user_input_textview) TextView addBuddyUserInput;
@ViewById(R.id.user_input_error_display) TextView inputErrorDisplay;
@ViewById(R.id.user_input_layout) RelativeLayout userInputLayout;
@ViewById(R.id.finding_friends_layout) RelativeLayout findingFriendsLayout;
@ViewById(R.id.no_permission_layout) RelativeLayout noPermissionsLayout;
@ViewById(R.id.add_from_contacts_snackbar) CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
@ViewById(R.id.add_from_contacts_listview) ListView contactsList;
@ViewById(R.id.add_from_contacts_searchview) SearchView searchView;
@ViewById(R.id.add_from_contacts_progressbar) ProgressBar progressBar;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private String currentQuery; // User's current query

/**
 * Grab a new instance of this fragment
 */
public static AddFromContactsFragment newInstance() {
    return new AddFromContactsFragment();
}

/**
 * Called after the views are set, place all view logic here
 */
@AfterViews
void afterAddFromContactsViews() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "after views start");
    contactsList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // iconify the widget, don't expand it by default
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    contactsList.setAdapter(addFromContactsActivityAdapter);
    handler = new ContactsHandler(findingFriendsLayout, addFromContactsActivityAdapter, getActivity(), contactsList); // The handler that will do all the hard stuff
    if (sessionManager.getUserContactPermission()) {
        checkForPermissions();
    } else {
        createAskForContactPermissionDialog();
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "after views end");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "on create start");
    sessionManager = SessionManager.getInstance(getActivity());
    databaseHelper = LBDatabaseHelper.getInstance(getActivity());
    timer = new Timer();
    addFromContactsActivityAdapter = new AddFromContactsActivityAdapter(getActivity(), this, new ArrayList<Buddy>()); // Instantiate so handler doesn't get a null one
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "on create end");
}
```

onCreate() is called in the fragment but not @AfterViews method. Can anybody help? Thanks. Also, the new classes ARE being generated by AA.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, figured it out relatively quickly, but I'll leave this here in case others experience the issue themselves.

The answer was the tricky newInstance() method I called to grab an instance of the Fragment.

```
/**
* Grab a new instance of this fragment
*/
public static AddFromContactsFragment newInstance() {
return new AddFromContactsFragment();
}
```

This needs to be revised to return a Fragment of the generated type AddFromContactsFragment_. The underscore is important, as it's the Android Annotations version. Likewise (which I already knew), when Intents are created you must use the '_' suffixed version of the Activity to make them.